# PHP Redirection not working, session has been started

Tags: php, redirect

I'm trying to get PHP redirection to work, in a login form, however, it is not working. Here's the code if the authentication is successful.

```
$success = (isset($_POST['uri'])) ? '' : '/index.php';

if ($rs->num_rows) {

    $qn = $db->query("SELECT userid FROM sessions");
    $svt = array();
    $vbs = $rs->fetch_assoc();

    while ($row = $qn->fetch_assoc()) {
        $svt [] = $row ['userid'];
    }

    if (in_array($vbs ['userid'], $svt)) {
    } else {
        set_session(array_merge($vbs, array('expires' => time() + (30 * 60))));
        $_SESSION['secure3d']['expires'] = time() + (5 * 60);
        header("Location: $success"); // this isn't working but the session is set.
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: did you check the the else statement has been reached? Or if some string were outputed before header? (warning, error message for example)

Comment: You had a curly bracket to much (at least in your pasted code)

Comment: Do you have errors enabled? Include `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script and tell us what it says.

Comment: @Ismael, yep, it definately goes. I'm going to disable errorreporting, see if it fixes it, but I'm not getting a header warning.

Comment: @konsolenfreddy just fixed that :)

Comment: it works now that I've removed error reporting. Now, I have no idea what it was outputting because there was none that I could see.

Comment: just put the error reporting back online and post the error

Comment: okay than post your error reporting

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try $success as an absolute URI, something like http://mydomain.com/index.php e.g. in http/1.1 it has to be an absolute URI

Another popular error is that an whitespace is send before the header function. This can be happen if you have an include which ends with `"?> "`

Comment: It depents on the http-Version you use ... e.g. if you use http/1.1 it has to be absolute

Comment: Not anymore. HTTPbis says it can be relative. http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-18#page-45 -- Notably it should be a relative URL however, not an URI. (`Location: urn:x:12:AB:FF:00` is kinda pointless.)